# css3 viewport and initial-scale

Tags: html, css

I'm testing meta `viewport` but changing the `initial-scale` attribute have no effect. Can it be that the `viewport` setting is only take into account in mobile browsers and the desktop browsers just ignore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desktop browsers do not take account of `meta viewport`.

If you want to give desktop browsers an `initial-scale`, you can use the CSS3

```
transform: scale(x, y)
```

property.

Answer (score 0):

You can always re scale your browser actually.

But, if you actually want to test how your content looks through browser you should test on the device itself. The next best option would be through emulation maybe such as using an IDE that offers multiple browser support like Cloud9.